# How to get pixel values of text from image using OopenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I intend to get the text (Google) pixel value from a picture, but I don't know how to do that, can someone help me please?

the Content of img

============================

Google(谷歌)

Apple(苹果)

FACEBOOK

============================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use ocr. Opencv has some ocr built in. You can find some example code here: https://opencv-code.com/tag/ocr/